# Getting error while updating foreign key of a table with unique index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

There are some duplicates in a table say tableA, however of `id` of tableA is a foreign key in another table. So before deleting the records in tableA I would like to update the foreign key in this other table. This is the schema of the other table.

**Table Schema:**

```
id
foriegn_key_id
attribute_id

Indexes:
 "index_table_on_attribute_id_and_foriegn_key_id" UNIQUE, btree (attribute_id, foriegn_key_id)
```

Sample data:

```
 id    foriegn_key_id attribute_id 
 1      2               3
 2      1               3
 3      1               4
 4      1               5
```

Below is the code that I tried to update the foreign key.

```
Table.where(foriegn_key_id: 1).update(foriegn_key_id: 2)
```

However, when the try the above code I get the following error.
`ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`

For the records I am getting the error alone I would like to have it deleted.
Is looping through and updating individual record and deleting the record that gets `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` the only way or is there a simpler way?

Comment: @SebastianPalma that will do a single update query, but how does that handle deleting the record when the foreign_key_id is not unique, since that is the question?

I think the best way is to loop through the records as you say, I mean whatever way you will go, you need to check if it's unique or not and handle to that.

Comment: When I try update_all I am getting `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` and none of the record is getting updated.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for one object to be updated from a relation and the other to be deleted. The only possible way is to go through the loop there to check it.